# What does calc(.333 * (100vw - 12em)) mean?

Tags: html, responsive-design, srcset, responsive-images

Can someone please explain to me what `calc(.333 * (100vw - 12em))` means in the following line of HTML? And in particular the .333 value; where does that come from?

```
sizes="(min-width: 36em) calc(.333 * (100vw - 12em)),
       100vw"
```

Taken from http://ericportis.com/posts/2014/srcset-sizes/

> A length can be all sorts of things! A length can be absolute (e.g.
>   99px, 16em) or relative (33.3vw, as in our example). You’ll note that,
>   unlike our example, there are lots of layouts which combine both
>   absolute and relative units. That’s where the surprisingly
>   well-supported calc() function comes in. Let’s say we added a 12em
>   sidebar to our 3-column layout. We’d adjust our sizes attribute like
>   so:

```
sizes="(min-width: 36em) calc(.333 * (100vw - 12em)),
       100vw"
```

I understand this much:

- (min-width: 36em) = media query
- calc(.333 * (100vw - 12em)) = rendered image size
- 100vw = default rendered image length

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's dissect this expression:

```
calc(.333 * (100vw - 12em))
```

`calc` means evaluate as an expression.

`vw` is `1%` of the view width, so `100vw` is `100%` of the view width.

`em` is the width of the capital m (`M`), so `12` of those would be the width of 12 ems, or the width of:  MMMMMMMMMMMM

`100vw - 12em` is thus the width minus twelve M's. If this post had a width of the view, then that would be something like:

```
      / from here                                                         to here \
```

`MMMMMM------------------------------------------------------------------------------MMMMMM`

`.333` of that is around `1/3`, so that would be one third of the width above. So, this width would look something like:

```
      / from here      to here \                          / or from here  to here \
```

`MMMMMM------------------------------------------------------------------------------MMMMMM`

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now (by re-reading the article and the answers here a hundred times). If you visualize your last sentence like you beautifully did with the 100vw - 12em part I'll mark this post as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well it means almost exactly one third (0.33...) of (a hundred percent of the viewport's width minus 12em).

> Let’s say we added a 12em sidebar to our 3-column layout. We’d adjust
>   our sizes attribute like so...

So, apparently he has a three column layout (hence the 0.33... one third) and he wants to make space for a 12em wide column. So he takes that from the calc()

Hope you got it now.

Answer (score 0):

I like to test CSS dimensions with JS, you can thoroughly figure out how relation between values and units works.

```js
var samp = document.getElementById('samp');
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

myForm.addEventListener('input', function(event){
    var t = event.target;
    t.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = t.value + t.getAttribute('data-unit');
    setWidth();
});

window.onload = function(){
 setWidth();
};

function setWidth(){
    var el = myForm.elements;
 var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
 var lnh = sheet.cssRules.length;
    var sel = "width: calc(" + el[1].value + " * (" + el[2].value + "vw - " + el[3].value + "em))";
    
 sheet.insertRule("#samp {"+sel+"}", lnh);
    output.innerHTML = sel;
}
```

```css
input[type='range'] {
  width: 60%;
}

p {
  margin:0;
  font-family:monospace;
}

#samp {
  background-color:#33aaff;
  height:40px;
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="myForm">
  <fieldset>
    <label>
      <input type="range" value=".333" min=".1" max="1" step=".001" data-unit="">
      <span>.333</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="range" value="100" min="1" max="100" step="1" data-unit="vw">
      <span>100vw</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="range" value="12" min="0" max="50" step=".2" data-unit="em">
      <span>12em</span>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <p id="output"></p>
  </fieldset>
</form>


<div id="samp"></div>
```